# Are there performance benefits from refactoring as shown in the codeacademy course?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm currently running through the CodeAcademy Ruby course and have hit a refactoring section.

Examples are

```ruby
if 1<2
       puts 'string'
end

puts "One is less than two!" if 1 < 2
puts 1 < 2 ? "One is less than two!" : "One is not less than two."
```

And others like if/elif/else statements to case statements as well as using the 'implicit return' syntax and swapping a for loop to

```ruby
3.times do
  puts "I'm a refactoring master!"
end
```

Are there any benefits to this other than simply making it more readable? In Python there are pythonic ways of doing things and it seems this is the same in Ruby. However if you do program in multiple language and can't remember the conventions for each it seems to make more sense to just keep it simple and leave a for loop as it is - likewise for other statements unless there is actually a performance benefit to this.

Comment: It's opinion, but I disagree with "it seems to make more sense to just keep it simple and leave a for loop as it is" taken generally. I guess it's fine if you write code for yourself, and never professionally. However, following convention is about making code sharable and accessible to others. Code written in a personal-comfort-first style, whatever the driving factors behind it, is often less pleasant to work on by anyone who maintains it or inherits your projects. My least favourite - and common - fault here is ignoring conventions for modularisation, leading to non-navigable code.

Comment: You make a fair point Neil, I guess when I was thinking about this at the time I was more concerned about my own code since I'm now in the earlyish stage of learning - that was a mistake. You are 100% right that I should be taking other developers into account and that sticking to conventions are a good way to do this.  Thanks for making me think about  this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the one liner is more of a Ruby-ist way. Nevermind, you can see about the speed for yourself with the use of `benchmark` module.

See the sped diff for yourself:

```
require 'benchmark'

iterations = 100000000

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  # joining an array of strings
  bm.report do
      (1..iterations).each do
          if 1<2
      true
    end
    end

  end

  # using string interpolation
  bm.report do
      (1..iterations).each do
        true if 1<2
    end
  end

   # using string interpolation
  bm.report do
      (1..iterations).each do
         1 < 2 ? true: false
    end
  end
end
```

Results:

```
       user     system      total        real
   5.850000   0.020000   5.870000 (  5.885982)
   5.780000   0.020000   5.800000 (  5.826295)
   5.600000   0.020000   5.620000 (  5.640354)
```

Comment: Given the number of iterations required to get these values, and likely cost of the comparison operator included, there is no meaningful difference shown here that would over-ride code style concerns. But +1 for showing how to measure in Ruby, which is always a solid answer to "what is faster?".

Comment: Exactly, I am not even pointing out the fastest way, because the difference is so small, that if you run the benchmark multiple times .. any of those 3 might be the fastest.

Comment: Any halfway decent compiler (I'm pretty sure at least Rubinius and JRuby+Truffle and JRuby, maybe MagLev too) will completely optimize the all of the loops away so that you basically end up with the assembly equivalent of `for (int i = 0; i++; i < 100000000) { // empty }`. IOW, you are benchmarking, how fast the CPU can increment a register. Maybe, the compiler will even optimize the loop away completely, so that you are essentially benchmarking `bm.report do; end`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Ruby (MRI) doesn't compile - at least not to native machine code - not sure exactly what it will optimise here. In theory you can code things in Ruby so that 1 is greater than 2 . . . so it is not obvious.

Comment: @NeilSlater: Ruby is a language, languages don't compile, compilers do. And there are several Ruby implementations which compile, in fact, at the moment, *all* of them do (MRI is the only one which doesn't, but MRI is obsolete, it's no longer being maintained). JRuby+Truffle, JRuby, Rubinius, IronRuby, MagLev, MacRuby, Topaz, they all compile to native code eventually. A couple of years ago, there was a talk by one of the Rubinius developers, which showed, how a benchmark from the YARV testsuite, which was *supposed* to test method dispatch performance got compiled into exactly the empty

Comment: … `for` loop I showed above (and thus completely eliminating any and all method dispatch from the very naively written method dispatch benchmark), precisely *because* thanks to de-optimization and dynamic speculative optimization, the compiler *does* know (or at least can assume) wether or not a method was overridden or monkey-patched. And that was a couple of years ago, Rubinius has only been getting better since then, and JRuby is even farther ahead thanks to the millions spent optimizing the various JVMs.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I'm behind on the other versions, and that is interesting to read, thanks! But are you sure MRI Ruby has become obsolete/un-maintained? I was under the impression that it was not only still active, but also by far the most commonly used implementation. Where can I find news that it has become un-maintained?

Comment: . . . I guess this is MRI -> YARV (which a lot of sources still call MRI Ruby, hence my confusion)? Regardless of the name of this "mainstream" version, it doesn't compile to native code, and I would suspect does *not* do the kinds of optimisation that you are concerned about with your original comment.

Comment: Thanks to all who contributed, the benchmark module is particularly useful. Thank you also for your comments on optimisation, I am aware that a compiler can often optimise better than we can ourselves - I wasn't sure if this was the case with Ruby.